# How to get element based on their innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, selectlist

I have a `for` loop where I am iterating over array `selected` items. I want to get the element from `select` list where my `value` is equal with `innerText` of `select list`. How I can do that using `jQuery` ?

I have tried this, but got stuck

```
 var selectedClubs = $('#select2-3 option:selected');
               
    console.log(selectedClubs[0].innerText);

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedClubs.length; i++) {
        if (selectedClubs[i].innerText == value) {
        var c = $("#select2-3 option:contains(" + selectedClubs[i].innerText + "')");
        console.log(c.innerText);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the loop if you're using `:contains`:

```js
var selectedClub = $(`#select2-3 option:selected:contains("${value}")`);
```

Alternatively you can use `filter()`:

```js
var selectedClubs = $('#select2-3 option:selected');
var selectedClub = $selectedClubs.filter((i, el) => el.innerText === value);
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to get element from `$('#select2-3')` list, and then remove it from selected items.

Comment: Well that's an important detail which you should have mentioned in the question. To do it just call `remove()` on the selector.